# ValueError: Invalid parameter for estimator RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am tuning SGD classifier using RandomizedSearchCV in Scikit-learn version 0.18.1 python 2.7.13 . I got this error and do not know what is wrong !

(Note I got a similar error also when I tried random forest . I tried SVM and LGBM classifiers using same code (but different param_grid) and did not get an error )

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator RandomizedSearchCV. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

The code of tuning the classifier :

```
from sklearn.metrics.classification import precision_recall_fscore_support
import sklearn

def clf_score(clf_model,param_grid,model_name=None):
    from sklearn.metrics import f1_scorer
    from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
    def avg_score(xx,stance_train):
        prec, recall, f, support = precision_recall_fscore_support(xx, stance_train, labels=[2, 1, 0],
                                                               beta=1)
        faverage=(f[0]+f[1])*0.5
        return faverage
    f1_scorer = make_scorer(avg_score,greater_is_better=True)
    clf_model=sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(verbose=3,estimator=clf_model, param_distributions=param_grid, cv=CV,scoring=f1_scorer,n_iter=20,random_state=99)
    clf_model.fit(X_train, stance_train)
    test_predict = clf_model.predict(X_test)
    return test_predict


SGD = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(random_state=99,n_jobs=-1)
param_grid = {
                'learning_rate':['constant','optimal','invscaling'],
                'eta0':[0.0,0.01,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7],
                'alpha':[0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1]}
test_prediction= clf_score(SGD, param_grid)
```

Here are the output and the details of the error

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 20 candidates, totalling 100 fits
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.210678, total=   1.4s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    1.5s remaining:    0.0s
D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1113: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.039474, total=   1.7s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    3.4s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.356784, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.351759, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.370766, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1, score=0.353070, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1, score=0.102564, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1, score=0.394590, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1, score=0.344262, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.1, score=0.331461, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01, score=0.277067, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01, score=0.040541, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01, score=0.497475, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01, score=0.351759, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.01, score=0.343434, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5 ................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5, score=0.343452, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5 ................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5, score=0.126623, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5 ................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5, score=0.429521, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5 ................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5, score=0.342857, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5 ................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.5, score=0.314815, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7, score=0.159236, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7, score=0.000000, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7, score=0.353234, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7, score=0.353234, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.7, score=0.353234, total=   1.4s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.277067, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.040541, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.497475, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.351759, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ...................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.343434, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.277067, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.040541, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.497475, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.351759, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3 ....................
[CV]  alpha=0.001, learning_rate=optimal, eta0=0.3, score=0.343434, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 .....................
[CV]  alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.159236, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 .....................
[CV]  alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.000000, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 .....................
[CV]  alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.353234, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 .....................
[CV]  alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.353234, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 .....................
[CV]  alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.353234, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.243056, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.372145, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.368362, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.351759, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.0001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1, score=0.346734, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3, score=0.327743, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3, score=0.063291, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3, score=0.407876, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3, score=0.345745, total=   1.3s
[CV] alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3 ..................
[CV]  alpha=0.01, learning_rate=invscaling, eta0=0.3, score=0.341837, total=   1.2s
[CV] alpha=0.1, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.0 .....................
Fitting 5 folds for each of 20 candidates, totalling 100 fits
[CV] alpha=0.001, learning_rate=constant, eta0=0.1 ...................
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1585, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/Mycode-newtrials - Copy/stance_detection -norelieff-lgbm - randomizedsearch.py", line 1608, in <module>
favg_sgd,cv_sgd,tuned_sgd=feature_selection_class(Relieff_neighbors,Relieff_features,LDA_topics,LDA_passes,w2v_features,w2v_min_wc,w2v_ctxt,down_sampling,skip_cbow,stance_train,stance_test,clf_to_use,N=2000,method=METHOD)
  File "D:/Mycode-newtrials - Copy/stance_detection -norelieff-lgbm - randomizedsearch.py", line 1507, in feature_selection_class
favg_sgd,cv_sgd,tuned_sgd = computescores(Relieff_neighbors, Relieff_features, LDA_topics, LDA_passes, w2v_features, w2v_min_wc, w2v_ctxt,down_sampling, skip_cbow, tweets_test, tweets_train, TARGET, allfeatures, favor_words, against_words,favor_tags,against_tags, clf_to_use, N, method)
  File "D:/Mycode-newtrials - Copy/stance_detection -norelieff-lgbm - randomizedsearch.py", line 914, in computescores
favg_gnb, cv_gnb, tuned_gnb = clf_score(SGD, param_grid)
  File "D:/Mycode-newtrials - Copy/stance_detection -norelieff-lgbm - randomizedsearch.py", line 802, in clf_score
clf_model.fit(X_train, stance_train)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1190, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, groups, sampled_params)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 564, in _fit
for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
self.results = batch()
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 227, in _fit_and_score
estimator.set_params(**parameters)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 291, in set_params
(key, self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator RandomizedSearchCV. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Note:
I searched and found some people had a similar error but the problem appeared because they used pipeline and did not append the classifier name to the param_grid .. But I am not using pipeline ..

Comment: I tried to use python 3.5 , it gave me error that the parameter "eta0" value must be greater than zero . So I removed 0.0 from the param_grid and it worked well .. However , the default value for this parameter is 0.0 ! .

Comment: But for Random Forest classifier , python 2.7 gives me an error (similar to the error I posted) .. However , I tried to use python 3.5 , it did not give me an error , it worked well without changing anything in the param_grid!

Comment: The default value of eta0 is 0.0 because its not used by the default learning rate ‘optimal’. When you change the learning rate, you must change eta0.

Comment: The params you have specified are for SGDClassifier, so they will not work with RandomForestClassifier, hence the error. Please post the complete codes and both errors in python2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it for the part of the estimator:

```
param_grid = {
                'sgdclassifier__learning_rate':['constant','optimal','invscaling'],
                'sgdclassifier__eta0':[0.0,0.01,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7],
                'sgdclassifier__alpha':[0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1]}
```

should work!